# Symfony 4, how get the root path directory (or /src path) properly from a Service Class ? ( error : 'Call to a member function get() on null')

Tags: symfony, symfony4

In Symfony 4, from a controller I can get the root path of my project via :

```
// From a Controller Class, in the src/Controller dir

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
// ...
Class myController extends Controller{
// ...
// in a public method
$rootDir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
```

But how can I get the root path from a Service Class ? 
I tried this (ugly) way

```
// From a Service Class, in the src/Service dir

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
// ...
Class myService extends Controller{
// ...
// in a public method
$rootDir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
```

But when I did that, I get the error :

```
"Call to a member function get() on null"
```

Why this solution does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is the same, but you can inject the ParameterBaginterface in the constructor, so you have access to all parameters.

And with this, you dont have to define the service, because autowiring makes your live easier.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

class MyService
{
    private $parmeterBag;

    public function __construct(ParameterBagInterface $parameterBag)
    {
        $this->parameterBag= $parameterBag;
    }
}
```

Now you can access your parameters over $this->parameterBag->get('your_parameter');

Answer (score 9):

Symfony provides a parameter `kernel.project_dir` that can be used inside the service container that you can inject into services or get from the container (inside the controller):

```
$this->getParameter('kernel.project_dir');
```

In a Service you would just inject it into the constructor:

```
class MyService
{
    private $projectDir;

    public function __construct(string $projectDir)
    {
        $this->projectDir = $projectDir;
    }
}
```

In your configuration you might have to ensure the string is passed properly, either by setting it directly for this specific service:

```
# config/services.yaml

...

services:

    ...

    App\MyService:
        arguments:
            $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Alternatively you can bind this parameter to the variable name, so that the configuration automatically recognizes it:

```
# config/services.yaml

...

services:
    _defaults:
        ...
        bind:
            $projectDir: '%kernel.project_dir%'
```

Then all services (registered inside that config file), which have a parameter `$projectDir`, will get the value from that parameter.

Comment: The approach with the parameters is not bad, but why not use the ParameterBagInterface in constructor instead of defining the service? Most of time, you will have to get more then one paraemter from services.yaml ( when the project is grows)

Comment: that means I must add every time the concerned service in the services.yaml file if I want access to this variable ? Is there a way for add a variable automatically to all existing services ? (without add manually each service in the config file ?)

Comment: thanks for your answer @dbrumann , but I prefer rebru answer :)

Comment: Ok, but just to answer your question in the previous comment, when using `bind` all services which have an argument `$projectDir` will automatically get the value. This will also make it easier if you want to change the path to something else or if you want to provide multiple paths. When using the ParameterBag the main drawback is, that when the value you get from the bag does not exist you will get an error once the code is executed. With my configuration you will instantly get feedback, that the selected parameter is not configured when the container is built.